# Reusing part of Grails criteria closure

Tags: grails, groovy, closures

I have a fairly large criteria closure in my Grails application, and I would like to reuse part of it in several places in my application. Rather than duplicating the section I need to reuse, I'd like to define this as a separate closure and reference it wherever it is needed, but I am struggling a bit with the syntax.

This is a simplified / cut down version, but essentially my criteria looks something like this:

```
def criteriaClosure = {
    and {
        // filtering criteria that I'd like to reuse in lots of places
        or {
            names.each { name ->
                sqlRestriction(getFilteringSql(name), [someId])
            }
        }

        if (isOrganisationChild(childDefaultGrailsDomainClass)) {
            sqlRestriction(getFilteringSql(domain), [someArg])
        }

        // filtering criteria that's specific to this particular method
        sqlRestriction(getSomeOtherSql(), [someOtherArg])
    }
}

def criteria = domain.createCriteria()
def paginatedList = criteria.list([offset: offset, max: max], criteriaClosure)
```

I've tried defining the part of the closure I want to reuse as a variable, and referencing it in my criteria closure, however the restrictions it defines don't seem to be applied.

```
def reusableClosure = {
    and {
        or {
            names.each { name ->
                sqlRestriction(getFilteringSql(name), [someId])
            }
        }

        if (isOrganisationChild(childDefaultGrailsDomainClass)) {
            sqlRestriction(getFilteringSql(domain), [someArg])
        }
    }
}

def criteriaClosure = {
    and {
        reusableClosure() //this doesn't seem to work
        sqlRestriction(getSomeOtherSql(), [someOtherArg])
    }
}
```

I'm sure this must be a pretty straightforward thing to do, so apologies if it's a daft question. Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you have to pass the delegate down to the `reusableClosure`, ie:

```
def criteriaClosure = {
    and {
        reusableClosure.delegate = delegate
        reusableClosure()
        sqlRestriction(getSomeOtherSql(), [someOtherArg])
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. - incidentally, why are the parentheses after 'reusableClosure' necessary?

Comment: Cool :-) Because that calls the closure (which returns the `and` block into the Criteria)