# Grails include closure in createCriteria

Tags: grails, grails-orm, criteria

I have a grails application in which I now need to do a search. I have created a closure which contains the common conditions.

```
def criteria = {
        if(pageSize){
            delegate.maxResults( pageSize )
        }
        if(offset){
            delegate.firstResult( offset )
        }
    ........
}
```

And then i want to use this inside create criteria alone with some specific conditions

```
objects = DomainObkect.createCriteria().list {

                    ne "booleanCheck", true
                    eq "value", value
                    criteria
                }
```

Is there a way for this to take effect? Now the criteria options are not being executed

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Sure.
Something like:

```
Closure searchRestriction = { builder ->
            if(pageSize){
                builder.maxResults( pageSize )
            }
            if(offset){
                builder.firstResult( offset )
            }
        }
        def criteria = DomainObkect.createCriteria()
        objects = criteria.list {
            ne "booleanCheck", true
            eq "value", value
            searchRestriction(criteria)
        }
```

Comment: Is there a way where I can use the delegate and still be able to do this? because inside searchRestriction I also need to access namedQueries of the domain object

Comment: Maybe better to use DetachedCriteria to simplify managing your searching closures? DetachedCriteria more flexible then regular criterias.
http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/GORM.html#detachedCriteria

Answer (score 0):

This question is asked earlier as well
[Reusing part of Grails criteria closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194137/reusing-part-of-grails-criteria-closure)

You can use [namedqueries](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/namedQueries.html) and you delegate criterias as well. Some of the blogs that you can check
http://www.tothenew.com/blog/grails-data-binding-criteria-reuse/
http://www.tothenew.com/blog/reusing-grails-criteria-for-multiple-domains-using-closure-delegate/

Comment: I tried the above by having the following lines inside the list method, "criteria.delegate = delegate" & "criteria()" but in doing so, i'm unable to invoke certain methods such as "delegate.inCountMethod" inside the closure